# what is a good mocking framework to start mocking with in asp.net MVC? (novice and probably not a hardcore mocker)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, frameworks, mocking

i want to use mocking in my unit tests.

Till now i more programmed 'tests' and not 'unittests' because i tested whole program flows, but reading discussions i can see the beauty of a mock object, from time to time.

But, looking around, there are a lot of frameworks available, and i want to make sure i start with a good one, because i'd like to invest time in learning a mock framework only once.

So as i said in the title, i'm a novice for mocking, using asp.net mvc, and don't think i'll be a hardcore mocker, investigating the edges of a mocking framework.

To give you an idea of what i like in the IOC frameworks i like unity and structuremap.

Michel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used both [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) and [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) as part of ASP.NET MVC projects with great success. While in the past these frameworks differed quite a bit, their feature sets have converged over the years and so either one would be a good choice.

Since you're specifically targeting MVC, you should consider [what Phil Haack has to say](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/23/comparing-moq-to-rhino-mocks.aspx) as well.

Comment: @Michel Check out the comments on this post as well, as Oran (author of Rhino Mocks) and Kzu (author of Moq) go back and forth for a while. It's iron-sharpening-iron if you ask me.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). I previously tried Rhino, but I personally find the Moq API to be slicker.

Comment: +1 I think the Moq API is extremely newbie-friendly and really easy to get into. I've had discussions with friends who argue that Rhino is more powerful, and that may be the case, but after using both of them I find Moq to be relatively easy to just jump right into.

Comment: @Pandincus Agreed. I initially started with Rhino, and then tried Moq, so I've used both. I stayed with Moq. I just find the Moq API flows much more easily than Rhino.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Say you have a class `MyClass` defined as follows:

```
public class MyClass{

    private IMyDependency dependency;

    public MyClass(IMyDependency dependency){
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void DoSomething(){
        //invoke a method on the dependency
        this.dependency.DoWork();
    }

}
```

`IMyDependency` is declared like this:

```
public interface IMyDependency{
    void DoWork();
}
```

Now using Moq, you could test that the dependency is called like so:

```
public void DoSomethingWillInvokeDoWorkCorrectly()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IMyDependency>();
    mock.Setup(imd => imd.DoWork()).Verifiable();
    var sut = new MyClass(mock.Object);
    sut.DoSomething();
    //Verify that the mock was called correctly
    mock.Verify();
}
```

Now that was a very simple example, so lets spice it up a little.

public class MyClass2{

```
    private IMyDependency2 dependency;

    public MyClass2(IMyDependency2 dependency){
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void DoSomething(int i){
        //invoke a method on the dependency
        this.dependency.DoWork(i * 2);
    }

}
```

`IMyDependency2` is declared like this:

```
public interface IMyDependency2{
    void DoWork(int i);
}
```

A test method that tests that the correct parameter is passed to the dependency could look like this:

```
public void DoSomethingV2WillInvokeDoWorkCorrectly()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IMyDependency2>();
    int parameter = 60;
    mock.Setup(imd => imd.DoWork(It.Is<int>(i => i == 2 * parameter)).Verifiable();
    var sut = new MyClass2(mock.Object);
    sut.DoSomething(parameter);
    //Verify that the mock was called correctly
    mock.Verify();
}
```

As you can see, the `Setup` method now adds a constraint on the parameter passed to `DoWork`, saying that it is an int the value of which must be twice the value of the `parameter` variable.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Funny though that the most examples were without any setup but only use 'Expect', but that will clear itself as i start working with it.